# CakePHP 3.x - how to use sum in find query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to get agregation result of the query that I'm attaching. I've been struggling for days and I don't seem to find the solution for this. Help would be appreciated

These are the models:

```
class EventsPromotersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['Events', 'Promoters'],
            'hasMany' => ['Payments'] 
        ]);
    }
}

class EventsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'hasMany'=> ['TicketTypes'],
            'belongsToMany' => ['EventsPromoters' => ['through' => 'EventsPromoters']]
        ]);
    }
}

class PromotersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['MultimediaFiles'],
            'belongsToMany' => ['EventsPromoters' => ['through' => 'EventsPromoters']]
        ]);
    }
}

class PaymentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['Promoters'],
            'hasMany' => ['Sales']
        ]);         
    }
}

class SalesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['TicketTypes', 'Payments']
        ]); 
    }
}

class TicketTypesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['Events'],
            'hasMany' => ['Sales']
        ]); 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the amount of `TicketTypes` (`sum(Sales.quantity)`) sold by `Promoters`.

This is my find method:

```
$query= $this->EventsPromoters
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Promoters' => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['Promoters.id', 'Promoters.name'])
            ;
        },
        'Payments.Sales.TicketTypes' => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['TicketTypes.id', 'TicketTypes.name'])
            ;
        }
    ])
    ->innerJoinWith('Events', function ($q) use($event_slug) {
            return $q->where(['Events.slug' => $event_slug]);
    })
;
```

The find method is working properly. Now I have to add the aggregation, but I do not know how.

What I expect is something like this:

```
  'promoter' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
                'id' => (int) 101,
                'name' => 'Lucas Moura',
                  'ticket_types' => [
                        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
                            'id' => (int) 101,
                            'name' => 'Primera Preventa',
                            'sales' => 3 <<<<<< AGGREGATION
                            '[new]' => false,
                            '[accessible]' => [
                                '*' => true
                            ],
                            '[dirty]' => [],
                            '[original]' => [],
                            '[virtual]' => [],
                            '[errors]' => [],
                            '[repository]' => 'TicketTypes'
                        }
                        (int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
                            'id' => (int) 102,
                            'name' => 'Palco VIP',
                            'sales' => 9 <<<<<< AGGREGATION
                            '[new]' => false,
                            '[accessible]' => [
                                '*' => true
                            ],
                            '[dirty]' => [],
                            '[original]' => [],
                            '[virtual]' => [],
                            '[errors]' => [],
                            '[repository]' => 'TicketTypes'
                        }
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the [**docs about using SQL functions**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)? What's the actual technical problem that you are facing? "_I don't know how_" leaves a lot of room for interpretation.

Comment: Hi @ndm. I don't know how to add the aggregation (sum). Please look at the code that I expect. I want to retrieve the amount of ticket type sold by promoters, without information about the payment and sales, just the amount.

Comment: did You tried to use [Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields)?

Comment: Having the same issue here, does anybody know how can be that achived?? Gonna try Virtual fields later @BogdanKuštan and let you know.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan In which model do you think I should use virtual field? Promoters, right?

Comment: Do you want to get sum result from associative table ?

Comment: @dfc where You want to get sale, so in Your case on `TicketTypes` model

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue and my solution was create virtual fields, i dont know if is the best way, but works for me. good luck.